# AngularJs new line after special character when binding

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have an angularJS project where I requested data from the server and the returned JSON object with a list of countries name like this :

```
$scope.countries=[{
   countriesName : 'USA, England, Germany, France'
}];
```

so when I bind the data to render it in view I use **`ng-repeat`** like this :

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
          <td>{{country.countriesName }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the current view :

```
Countries Name :
-----------------
USA, England, Germany,France
```

but I want in the view to split this names by special character which in this case `(,) **and then write the next name in new line at the same**

so the expected view something like this :

```
Countries Name :
-----------------
USA,
England,
Germany,
France
```

***Note:***
-That binding the countries name returns in one string line and I bind this names in  in a table **at once time**

-I want one **`<td>`** with 4 different lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate different `div`s after splitting the `countriesName` by a space. Since `div`s have block display, the contents will automatically take up new lines.

I prefer this approach to not deal with sanitizing the generate HTML content (by using `<br>` tags), as it will require including `ngSanitize` module.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{
      countriesName: 'USA, England, Germany, France'
    }];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="country in countries">
          <div ng-repeat="line in country.countriesName.split(' ')">
            {{line}}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
          <td ng-repeat="name in country.countriesName.split(',')">
              {{ name }}
          </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```